# How to select all children text but excluding a tag in Selenium's XPath selector?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have this html:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Title 1</h1><br><br>

    <h2>Sub-Title 1</h2>
    <br><br>
    Description 1.<br><br>Description 2.
    <br><br>

    <h2>Sub-Title 2</h2>
    <br><br>
    Description 1<br>Description 2<br>
    <br><br>

    <div class="infobox">
        <font style="color:#000000"><b>Information Title</b></font>
        <br><br>Long Information Text
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get all text in `<div id="content">` in Selenium's **find_element_by_xpath** function but excluding `<div class="infobox">`'s content, so the expected result is like this:

```
Title 1


Sub-Title 1


Descripton 1.

Descripton 2.


Sub-Title 2


Descripton 1.
Descripton 2.
```

I can get it by using this code in online XPath tester:

```
//div[@id="content"]/descendant::text()[not(ancestor::div/@class="infobox")]
```

But if I pass the code to selenium's find_element_by_xpath, I will get `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException`.

```
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="content"]/descendant::text()[not(ancestor::div/@class="infobox")]')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The xpath used inside [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) has to point to an element, not a text node and not an attribute.

The easiest approach here, would be to find the parent tag, find the child tag which text you want to exclude and remove the child's text from the parent's text:

```
parent = driver.find_element_by_id('content')
child = parent.find_element_by_class_name('infobox')
print parent.text.replace(child.text, '')
```

Comment: Great answer! I know you mentioned this is easiest. But can the xpath be written for this?

Comment: @Saifur thank you, it can, though `find_element_by_xpath()` cannot be used for this. The other option I thought was to evaluate the xpath with js and `execute_script()`.